# Java: notifyObservers not concurrent?

Tags: java, design-patterns, concurrency, observer-pattern, java.util.concurrent

I have 4 observers listening on an observable data. However one of my observer is slower and could take. I just saw the code of [notifyObserver](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Observable.java#Observable.notifyObservers%28java.lang.Object%29) as:-

```
  132       public void notifyObservers(Object arg) {
  133           /*
  134            * a temporary array buffer, used as a snapshot of the state of
  135            * current Observers.
  136            */
  137           Object[] arrLocal;
  138   
  139           synchronized (this) {
/**comment removed for clarity **/

  152               if (!changed)
  153                   return;
  154               arrLocal = obs.toArray();
  155               clearChanged();
  156           }
  157   
  158           for (int i = arrLocal.length-1; i>=0; i--)
  159               ((Observer)arrLocal[i]).update(this, arg);
  160       }
```

From the code it is clear that the observers are called one after another. As by design observers are independent in execution. Shouldn't function be calling them in concurrently and make `arg`as final?

curent time of execution is `t1+t2+t3+t4` which should have been `max(t1,t2,t3,t4)`. I could make `update` function of the observer non-blocking but that wouldn't be same and could cause some race condition as `notifyObservers()` will exit without the observer being completely executed.

Am I missing something behind this design? Is it intentional and there is no way I could reduce the time here?

Comment: What would making `arg` `final` change?

Comment: They use a copy of the `observers` array to be able to avoid synchronization. So your problem is somewhere else. Did you create an observer yourself ?

Comment: Also, _calling them concurrently_ **how**? On some default `Thread`? With an `ExecutorService`? With the common `ForkJoinPool`? What if your class (the observer(s)) isn't thread safe? How does it know?

Comment: Sorry by final I meant that arg should be final and ExecutorService was in my mind to achieve concurrency.

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue The above code is the actual code from Java 6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not part of the pattern to optimize execution time of notifying observers. Observers that have a long running task to do should start their own thread of execution and return immediately from `update()` instead of blocking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Spawning a thread from an observer will have consequences as it notify could come sooner before the observer could finish execution. Since I am sure that my observers are independent I would implement the pattern by myself!

Answer (score 2):

Context: the Observer implementation of in Java is a general implementation design to work for *many*, but not for *all* cases. The primary cause of calling the `update()` method sequentially is that many frameworks (e.g GUI and probably application code) is designed to be single-threaded and executing the observers in parallel would definitely lead to some race conditions.

Solution: Either execute your logic in a separate thread in your Observer's `update()` method (like Samuel explained), or, if you always want to execute the `update()` method in parallel, create your own implementation and use e.g an `ExecutorService` inside the `notifyObservers()` method.